# AJAX Refresh Blinks Screen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, refresh

I have an app that has a status screen that is meant to be displayed at all times in various places around the organization.  There are probably 50 different users inputting different pieces of data into it, and the status screen updates every 10 seconds with the new information.  It's pretty much a tracking board for widgets flowing through a process.

Currently, I do a refresh every 10 seconds which empties all the divs and then loops through the active widgets and places them where every they should go and color codes based on status and stuff like that.  However, there's a fraction of a second of a blink from when the javascript empties the divs and when they repopulate, and it's pretty annoying honestly.

My question is how to best update the status screen where there is no blink and things just empty out and pop in as needed.

My thinking at first is there a way to "freeze" the screen for 2 seconds and let it rewrite in the background then unfreeze so there isn't a blink.

OR, which would be MUCH MUCH MUCH cooler, is that some how I only update pieces that get updated within the 10 second intervals.  So if a widget goes from staging area to molding, it fades out of staging and fades into molding and none of the other divs are touched.  This would be cool because I could add some animations this way.  However, I'm not sure how to "efficiently" do this.  Maybe I have an "active array" that stores how everything is, and then the AJAX pulls a new array and executes changes where the two doesn't match?

Anyway, I'd like to know if there's a screen freeze, update in the background answer and if there's an like the second one described.

Sorry for the novel =(

Comment: I have no time to read the novel :P Please be precise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blink or flashing effect is consequence of the asynchronous behavior of ajax.

what is happening is that your divs are emptying, but your new data is not yet ready to fill them.

the solution is to house your divs' emptying and refilling in a callback that is passed to the successful completion of your ajax request.

Comment: Brilliant. Why didn't I think through that. I was thinking it was more of cpu processing time than server latency. I'll give this a go since I'm setup to try pretty easily.

Comment: for even smoother results, see my comment regarding `documentFragment` and `replaceChild`

Comment: Bah, didn't work. Added my ClearScreen function to the success part of AJAX. Would it matter to move the refresh and clear to Complete instead of Success?

Comment: I've made the change and haven't looked in awhile, but the blink is gone. I'm wondering if I didn't load the new one to the server or if I needed to hard refresh the page,  but this resolved it. I didn't move it to the complete section of th AJAX call, just in the success. The othe solutions here I'm sure would have worked and I will still try so that I can get se animations in, but that's version 1.2 probably o.O

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of your problem comes when you clear all the data out before repopulating it.

You could try two methods for fixing this.

Solution 1
Build a string of html when you get your new results back. Do this in a loop, adding to the string variable each time and then replace the html of a "wrapper" div with the new html. You could make it fancy and do a fade in/fade out too.

```
var htmlString = '';
for(var i=0; i < jsonReturn.length; i++)
{
    htmlString += "<p>" + jsonReturn[i].data + "</p>";
}

$('#wrapper-div").empty().append(htmlString);
```

Solution 2
Give your html id's that are based on an id value from the data you're repopulating. This will be considerably more complicated but it would let you update single items in your display individually or only if they change.

```
<p id="data-spot-<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">Some display data</p>
```

Then in your javascript you would do

```
for(var i=0; i < jsonReturn.length; i++)
{
    $('#data-spot"+jsonReturn.id).empty().append("Some html string or data");
}
```

Comment: I really want #2 to be my end game because of the aesthetics of fade out and in but you're right, it'll be considerably more difficult. That will be an optimization for later. I'll come back here and post it when I do it though. I think option one is where it's at. Don't know why I didn't think of that!!!

Comment: With solution 1 - far better to use a document fragment and the replaceChild method - that way you build up what the screen should look like in the fragment without effecting the current visual, and replace the whole lot in one go far quicker than using innerHTML, or god forbid the jQueery .html()

Comment: If he's going with solution 1 the fade effect would alleviate a lot of the slowness of doing an innerHTML. Also, editing my code to do .html() the right jquery way.

Comment: I think you're on it. This sounds like it'll be the smoothest and not worry about latency or CPU time. It'll take me a bit to give it a go though because the status screen is fairly complex. Right now I pull all widgets and then use if statements to place each one in a loop. This method would want me to loop through each landing zone and then see if a widget should be in there. So I'll have to invert my logic I think

Comment: jquery.html() is still 6 times slower than innerHTML - and documentFragment is faster (5%) still

Comment: I'm not denying that at all. I completely agree. I just feel that if you're using jQuery, your priority is not really on speed of the application, but on ease of coding and maintaining and cross platform execution. Plus, I think people tend to want to be consistent with their language, use all jquery or all vanilla JS.

Comment: I had to look up documentFragment because I'd never heard of that before. I agree that it is a method I'd be looking into in the future for this type of problem.